# MacOS-app as replacement for snomD305-SIP

Tags: macos, voip

Problem: At work we have the snomD305-SIP hardware telephones, but due to the coronavirus we are all working from home now and don't have the phone with us.

Question: Is there an app for MacOS (or iOS/Android) that can connect to the same service, so we can accept incoming calls on the mac? What "features/capabilities" do we need to look for?

The macs have a VPN-connection into office, so we can access the webserver in the phone and read/modify settings if needed. But it's 20 pages with 50 settings each, so no idea where to start. :)

Answer (score 1):

AnySIP client should work. Try LinPhone for example:

https://www.linphone.org/